# What is wrong with my regexp (re.sub), accents (latin-1 pattern)?

Tags: python, regex

I'm brend new in python,

trying to extract and replace, by regex, substrings in a file.

my pattern :

(u'^([a-Z\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa9\xc3\xad\xc3\xb3\xc3\xba\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa3\xc3\xa2\xc3\xb5\xc3\xa2\xc3\xaa\xc3\xb4].*?)<', u'$1<')

**my code:**

```
# encoding: utf-8
# encoding: iso-8859-1
# encoding: win-1252

#coding: utf-8
import json
import sys
import codecs
import re
from datetime import datetime

#import os
#import fileinput


def myReplace(filename, replacePattern):
    contador = 0
    begin  = datetime.now() 
    with codecs.open(replacePattern, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
        replacePattern_json = json.load(f)

    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
        filedata = f.read()

    for pattern in replacePattern_json['padrao']:
        print(pattern['buscar'] , pattern['substituirPor'])
        print ('este padrão acima sera compilado agora')
        buscarPor = re.compile(pattern['buscar'], re.X)
        substituirPor = re.compile(pattern['substituirPor'])
        filedata = re.sub(buscarPor , pattern['substituirPor'], filedata)
        contador +=1

    newfilename = codecs.open ("new_"+ filename.split('.')[0] + ".xml","w+", encoding='utf-8')
    newfilename.write(filedata)
    newfilename.close()
    end =  datetime.now()
    timeelapsed = end -begin
    print(timeelapsed.seconds)
if __name__== "__main__":
    myReplace(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

**in my original json:**

```
{
         "buscar":"^([a-Záéíóúàãâõâêô].*?)<",
         "substituirPor":"<denominacao>$1</denominacao><"
}
```

**the error:** :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pageConverter.py", line 40, in <module>
    myReplace(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
  File "pageConverter.py", line 28, in myReplace
    buscarPor = re.compile(pattern['buscar'], re.X)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

**Python version** : Python 2.7.17

Please  could someone help me?

Comment: Greetings Orthophilos, can you edit your question to make it more clear what errors you've stumbled upon, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Ok. Just a while

Comment: Do you have a substantial reason to still use Python 2.7? It entered shut-down phase in 2015 and has officially been discontinued per 1 january 2020. All the other kids on the block use a much later version (we're up to 3.8 now).

Comment: That range `a-Z` is the problem, by the way. GREP sorts per Unicode character code, and that range is indeed invalid. It's like supplying a range `h-b`, that won't work either.

Comment: thanks a lot, and is there any alternative?

Comment: Orthopilos, `a-Z` is invalid. Alternatively, use `a-zA-Z`